# The requested URL / was not found on this server. Even though httpd-vhosts.conf and host file all seem to be correct

Tags: apache, wamp, http-status-code-404

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/mysite/"
    ServerName gamath
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/mysite/">
        AllowOverride All
         Order Deny,Allow  
            Allow from all
            Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   gamath

::1     localhost
::1     gamath
```

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/mysite/"
 ServerName gamath
 <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/mysite/">
  AllowOverride All
   Order Deny,Allow  
      Allow from all
   Require local
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1 gamath

::1     localhost
::1  gamath

Comment: How do you expect us to help you ?

Comment: Does the site run when you use the url `localhost/mysite`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache 2.4 you should amend your httpd-vhosts.conf file like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/mysite/"
    ServerName gamath
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/mysite/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

as these are Apache 2.2 syntax

```
Order Deny,Allow  
Allow from all
```

and

```
Require local
```

is Apache 2.4 syntax

If you actually want to allow access to your site form the universe then

```
Require all granted
```

Is the Apache 2.4 syntax

> Some upgrade documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Also make sure you have uncommented the include of httpd-vhosts.conf in the `httpd.conf` file

Also remember to restart Apache after you amend these file.

Comment: Thanks dude for the syntax update, but I still get the same error line returning, I'm using windows 2010 pc, and I'm using wamp64. Except for both .conf files mentioned above, I don't know what else to try? All I want is to be able to click on my files under "Your Virtualhosts" on the wamp localhost page so it shows my website I'm building. Any help would be unbelievably relieving. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access the site from the same machine that is running WAMPServer?

Comment: Have you reloaded the DNS cache after amending the HOSTS FIle. A reboot would do that

Comment: Yes, I am. I've installed wamp on my machine and I'm trying to create a form online with databases, it's just local tests for the moment. yes I've reloaded the dnscache. I haven't actually created a database server as I thought the php Web page files is all that's needed to get the links working on the wamp page. Could it be that I need to also create a database using mysql?

Comment: If you dont intend to use a database you dont need to create one. Does you site use a database?

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, not at the moment but eventually. It would be nice If I can get the links working. I've been looking through articles and seem to be getting most things right. But I still get the 404 error, I'm sure there's something I'm getting wrong.

Comment: Actually I just realised there is no `Windows 2010` there is an `Office 2010` So what is the Windows OS version that you are using?

Comment: Windows 10 currently